# How to use form validation and session in Spring MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, session

This is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("loginform.htm")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map<String, LoginForm> model) {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map<String, LoginForm> model) {
        String userName = "UserName";
        String password = "password";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginform";
        }

        loginForm = (LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");
        if (!loginForm.getUserName().equals(userName)
                || !loginForm.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return "loginform";
        }
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

I use this to validate form when user input username and password. But the question is when validate success, I want to add user information to session in this page. Please tell me how I can do that, I tried to add function

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
```

but it show nothing. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: instead of implementing security stuff by your self you should use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

---

To access sessions in Spring you have tree different ways:

- Work with the Http Session direcly (add the parameter `HttpSession session` to your controller method)
- [@SessionAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) - to access an specific field of you session
- Attaches beans to the session ([session scoped beans](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other))